# C# 'lock' the Form.BackColor

Tags: c#, winforms, backcolor

Basically I'm creating my own form

```
public class CryForm : System.Windows.Forms.Form
```

for several reasons, one of which is a very specific style.

Therefore I want the `Form.BackColor` property to be 'locked' to Black, so that it cannot be changed from 'outside'

```
CryForm1.BackColor = Color.whatevercolorulike
```

should not be possible anymore.

Is there any way to achieve this or should I come up with a completely different solution?

Comment: May I ask why you are not working with WPF instead? IMO it is more flexible and dynamic than winforms. With WPF you can limit values on dependencyproperties on `Window`s with coercion.

Comment: @Default no specific reason ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your need to is to 'lock' the background color of the form at design-time, probably the most efficient and least error-prone solution would be to override the `BackColor` property and mark with an attribute, then inherit from the form in the designer.

You could declare:

```
public class FixedBackgroundForm : Form
{
    protected new static readonly Color DefaultBackColor = Color.Black;

    [Browsable(false),
        DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    public override Color BackColor
    {
        get { return base.BackColor; }
        set { base.BackColor = value; }
    }

    public FixedBackgroundForm()
    {
        this.BackColor = DefaultBackColor
    }
}
```

Which would both set your form background color to `Black` automatically, *and* prevent changing of the background color from within the designer.

When you add new forms to your project, inherit from `FixedBackgroundForm`:

```
public partial class Form1 : FixedBackgroundForm
{
    ...
}
```

If you needed to "fix" the background color to black *no matter what*, simply use this line for the `BackColor` setter:

```
set { base.BackColor = DefaultBackColor; }
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work, although you won't get a compile time error when trying to set the property.

```
public override Color BackColor
{
    get { return Color.Black; }
    set { }
}
```

You can make it explicit that changing the `BackColor` is not supported. It will result in a runtime exception if anything is trying to change it:

```
public override Color BackColor
{
    get { return Color.Black; }
    set { throw new NotSupportedException("CryForm doesn't support changing the BackColor"); }
}
```

Comment: almost it's just missing the automatic 'defaulting' of the color but you are right

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to add this to the form load event:

```
this.BackColorChanged += (s, e2) =>
{
   if (this.BackColor != Color.Black)
      this.BackColor = Color.Black;
};
```

Comment: That wont work because the method to change the form backcolor probably occurs after form load.

Comment: @Maertin could you explain your reasoning? This is an event that triggers everytime the backcolor changes, specifically after the form has loaded.

Comment: @Default the method may work, but I dont think the form.load event is the correct place to put it. The form.load event has to be called for the method to be invoked.

Comment: @Maertin - I should have explicitly said that this gets added to the form load event handler and if there is a handler it then gets run when the form loads. Once this code runs in the form load the `BackColorChanged` handler will run every time that the background colour changes.

Comment: @Enigmativity @Maertin also: wouldnt it produce an endless loop of `BackColorChanged`?

Comment: @SaculRennorb - No, the `if` checks to see if the colour needs changing.

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
public new Color BackColor
{ 
    get { return Color.Black; }
}
```

to your code!

Comment: That won't stop code from simply doing `Control control = cryForm; control.BackColor = Color.Red;` But you can use `override` instead of `new` I think (and also override the setter).

Comment: @SaculRennorb Did you try overriding the setter using `override`? `override` certainly works on virtual properties as well as methods.

Comment: the thing is: it is indeed working, i CAN override the prop BUT: it wount change the behaviour...

Comment: @SaculRennorb - Why won't it change the behaviour?

Comment: @Enigmativity there was another problem somwhere else in my code, this solution does work fine(the one from the comments not the actual answer)